# Wheatstone bridge with capacitors needs to be balanced

Tags: wheatstone-bridge

Given the Wheatstone bridge shown with AC input, how does one obtain the relationship C2*R2=C1*R1? The impedance between any nodes does not appear to be able to simplified in a way that would make the relationship easily visible through transfer function analysis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpNF68.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This question originally came from here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105983/wheatstone-bridge-with-capacitors

Comment: My own personal experience is that I've never been able to get an AC Wheatstone Bridge to work as well as I've wanted it to!  I probably don't have enough hours into trying to make it better that would let me draw valid conclusions.  For my more recent forays into capacitative sensors, I just work them into an oscillator, and measure the frequency of the oscillator.  Quick, clean, easy, and I don't have to balance AC bridges.

Comment: Agreed, the method you speak of is definitely the standard method especially with the prevalent use of uControllers.

Answer (score 2):

If R2 is K times R1 then C1 has to be K times C2. It's as simple as that unless I'm missing something obvious. It's that by inspection.

At any frequency the impedance ratio of R1 to XC1 must be equal to R2 to XC2.

\$\dfrac{R_1}{\frac{1}{sC_1}}\$ = \$\dfrac{R_2}{\frac{1}{sC_2}}\$

Therefore R1C1 = R2C2

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in trying to simplify this circuit is that there appears to be an important node at any given point so no simplification appears possible. The key here is that the circuit must be **balanced**. This implies that Vout1 and Vout2 are at equal potentials. This means we can simplify this problem by only looking at each half separately.

If you think about it in terms of a voltage divider, you have to transfer the capacitors using the laplace transform. That works like this:
R->r
C->1/(Cs)

Now you have two voltage dividers, and in both cases, Vin and Vout must be equal. A transfer function is literally Vout/Vin. So if we find the transfer functions of each, we make them equivalent and we should end up with the relationship asked in the question, i.e. R1*C1=R2*C2.

\$ V_o=V_i*(\frac{R_1}{R_1+\frac{1}{C_1s}}) \$

\$ H(s) = \frac{V_o}{V_i} = \frac{R_1}{R_1+\frac{1}{C_1s}} \$

The second transfer function will be very similar looking. Then you just set them equal to each other:
\$ \frac{R_1}{R_1+\frac{1}{C_1s}} = \frac{R_2}{R_2+\frac{1}{C_2s}} \$

From here it's just algebra to rearrange the elements to get to the solution.